# How to derive closed-form solution to recurrence relation involving reciprocal

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have been trying to find the closed-form solution for:

$$T(n) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(T(n-1)+\dfrac{1}{T(n-1)}\right)$$

I wasn't getting anywhere, so I tried WolframAlpha, which gave me:

$$T(n) = -i\cot(k2^n)$$

For some $k$. So far so good. With a bit of manipulation, I ended up getting an answer:

$$T(n) = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{T(0)+1}{T(0)-1}\right)^{2^n}+1}{\left(\dfrac{T(0)+1}{T(0)-1}\right)^{2^n}-1}  $$

This appears to be correct. So, for all intents and purposes, I have my solution. I could probably work out a proof by "guessing" the formula and showing by induction that it fits the recurrence relation. But I find this method to be rather unsatisfactory. I'm looking for a direct way to derive the 2nd step.

I am somewhat familiar with the most basic homogeneous linear recurrences, so I can intuitively sort of see where the $\cot$ would pop from -- but none of the techniques I'm coming up with quite work. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have that
$$T(n)\pm 1=\frac{(T(n-1))^2\pm 2T(n-1)+1}{2T(n-1)}=\frac{(T(n-1)\pm 1)^2}{2T(n-1)}$$
we obtain
$$\frac{T(n)+1}{T(n)-1}=\left(\frac{T(n-1)+1}{T(n-1)-1}\right)^2$$
Now setting 
$$U(n)=\frac{T(n)+1}{T(n)-1}$$
gives
$$U(n)=(U(n-1))^2$$
Taking the logarithm,
$$\log U(n)=2\log U(n-1)$$
Setting $V(n)=\log U(n)$ gives
$$V(n)=2V(n-1)$$
to have
$$V(n)=2^n\cdot V(0)$$
from which we get the closed-form solution you wrote.

Comment: *Very* nice indeed.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much.